# In firefox is it possible to find where javascript function runs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser

I want to know which function runs when we click on an anchor on a site.

I am having an issue that when we click on an anchor, a function runs to retrive data from ajax. I want to find out where the ajax is called.

I am using jquery.

Are there any plugins for the task ?

**EDITED**

I am not able to figure out the function from the source. There are MANY minified scripts, with no selector to the required event.

Plugins are just an option. I am open to any alternatives to find the correct solution.

Comment: Why do you need a plugin? Search through the source to find the references to the function...

Comment: Inspect your anchor code and you'll find `ev` beside the Element. Click there.

Comment: well, searching through the page source happens to be too complicated, considering it uses MANY minified script.

Comment: and there are nothing calls present in the browser html source as well as the inspector.

Comment: @AAShakil This is what the anchor contains : `<a href="http://example.com/3895/3898/dashboard" class="selected external"><i class="fa fa-chart-bar"></i> <span>Home</span></a>` .

Comment: If your anchor uses JavaScript you'll find `ev` sign after your element. Have you find it?

Comment: @AAShakil Thank you. That is my answer.

Comment: @asdf Okay than I'm  adding this as an answer please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox has an option to inspect `JavaScript` function like html inspecting.

You'll find it near or after your `element` after inspecting source code as a `ev` sign.

Just click on the `ev` sign and you'll get what functions are working when you click on the `anchor`.

Here's an screenshot and documentation from [FireFox Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners)

[image]